# pentaho mysql datetime javascript comparison

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime, kettle, pentaho-spoon

**Hi Guys!**

I am having an issue, while comparing MySQL date time with format using javascript,

for an example: **2016-01-25 01:22:00**

i load it and trying to compare it with in the JavaScript scope, but its not working, am using **"Modified Java Script Value"** with in the **Pentaho Data Integration** aka **kettle**

Its not working and showing errors, that invalid date, can anyone time me what is the correct format with in JavaScript and what format is needed when comparing date time in the JavaScript scope? Do i need to change the format?

Comment: How do you try to compare? What kind of value do you compare with?

Comment: like 2016-01-25 01:22:00 < 2016-01-26 01:22:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found that you just need to replace "-" with "/" :)

**Example:**

**NOTE:** below code is from **Modified Java Script Value** with in Pentaho Data Integration.

Should be **forward slashes**, otherwise its not being accepted by the **DATE** constructor, **says invalid date** :(, i was trying to compare hard coded dates with the MySQL time stamp.

var d1 = new Date("2015/08/17 21:31:06");

var d2 = new Date("2015/08/17 21:31:07");

Alert(d1.getTime() < d2.getTime());

Interesting thing i have found is that, it can be compared with a time stamp from MySQL using **HYPHENS** between year-month-date, but to achieve that you have to first use **select step** in kettle and change the type of the field to **DATE** and use the format like **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"**

You can use your own formats, i was querying **MAGENTO** table, so i used this format

Still if there is anything more professional in terms of accomplishing this task, do share...